# Centralized Log Monitoring For Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension installed across different systems. I want a centralized place for log monitoring where all console logs can be redirected. Currently I am using Rollbar for error tracking but I want to get detailed logs along with error tracking

Comment: Could this help you? https://console.re/